# Double the size of a list of random integers, then sort and print it

Tags: python

Here, I have a list of random integers:

```
import random
list = [random.randint(0, 30) for x in range(6)]
pass
```

I want to double the size of this list, sort it, and print it. Here's what I've tried:

```
def list_doubled(list):
    doubled = []
    i = 0
    while i <= len(list):
        for item in list:
            doubled.append(list[i])
            doubled.append(list[i])
            i += 1
    print(doubled)

list_doubled(list)
```

This code is meant to only double the size of the list. When I run the program, I get "IndexError: list index out of range" with emphasis on lines 11 and 16.

Comment: You should never have a variable literally called `list`; that shadows the built-in name `list` and makes it inaccessible.

Comment: You're iterating once over a list. You don't need two nested loops. Either the `while` or the `for` will do

Comment: No need for any loops: `doubled = list + list`

Comment: As already mentioned the usage of list is no good style :). To double a list you just have to multiply it like this lisT = lisT*2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python you can double a list by just multiplying it by 2.

```
>>> import random
>>> nums = [random.randint(0, 30) for _ in range(6)]
>>> print(nums)
[5, 30, 28, 11, 19, 17]
>>> print(sorted(nums * 2))
[5, 5, 11, 11, 17, 17, 19, 19, 28, 28, 30, 30]
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating the list:

```
import random
numbers = [random.randint(0, 30) for x in range(6)]
```

Use extend to add the list to itself, in order to double it:

```
numbers.extend(numbers)   # or numbers += numbers
```

Or add as many random numbers as there are items in the list, if you need the additional numbers to also be random:

```
numbers.extend(random.randint(0, 30) for _ in range(len(numbers)))
```

use sort to sort it:

```
numbers.sort()
```

Use print to print it:

```
print(numbers)
```

Answer (score -2):

Change your `<=` to `<` in your while loop line `while i <= len(list):`. You also might want to look at the comments, they have good advise on additional potential bugs you might encounter.

Comment: This does not fix the problem and in fact creates a new problem.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel What do you mean? Seems bad but correct to me.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel is right, you still get the IndexError, but I'm unsure how it creates a new problem...

Comment: @KevinM No, it eliminates the IndexError. Did you not test it?

Comment: I misread it; I thought it proposed the opposite change. However, this still misses the problem that O(N^2) appends occur due to the nested loop.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Unclear what you mean. [It works](https://tio.run/##lU/LCoMwELznK/ZWQ0UsQilSv0SkpCTqQkxCTGn79anrg9pj95KdmZ2drHuH3pri4nyMODjrA3hhpB2YxjFABfUCM3rQhCRPocg5tNbDC9DQdKeSM2@YE@PImFQtkPUm7eOulUwI8JLBVCtFW5uZwKnN5@7Zo1YTvoJWZu@hojAMaqA8kr7KbmsmnFNmyaux4X/PIBwrOM2U83TqauKMLfhgPXZohC4P6fwPvgnr5Mb/3s5j/AA).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: the `while` loop is traversed only once, because the inner loop increments `i`.

Comment: Ah, of course, that's in the inner loop. What a strange approach to the code. Regardless, the outer loop should still be removed entirely, rather than being adjusted.

Comment: @KellyBundy I made a coding mistake on my end when retesting, d'oh...